# How to get iOS push notification token after app launch

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios8, push-notification

I am writing an iOS app which registers for push notification. I need to send the device token at regular intervals/whenever server requests.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
   //send to server
}
```

But this is happening only when the app launches. How to get to this callback on some other part of the app apart from launch so that it reaches the above code and sends the deviceToken to my server ?

I am thinking of this ( has to support iOS8 and also lower )

```
if( server requests token )
{
   if( [application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings) ] )
   {
      [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
   }
   else
   {
      [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert );
   }
}
```

Is this the right way of getting the deviceToken again in the middle of the app ( i.e after app launch ) . Please help

Comment: You have a serious problem around "send the device token at regular intervals/whenever server requests."

Comment: @erkanyildiz I know but the regular intervals is not too regular ( happens once in a month or two ) and server design change is not something I can do. Time-constraints.

Comment: There is a really serious design problem here. I don't know why it is required to send the token in addition to app launch. Incase of a token change (reinstall, restore on another device, expire etc..), app launch is OK for sending the new one to server. You do not need to make the app send the token explicitly at regular intervals. By the way, silent push is the only way that your server can make your app to send some data whenever it needs. But this works only when you already have a valid token.

Answer (score 0):

When ***didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken*** is called, you can save the registered token at Application level.

Create a ***@property*** at the AppDelegate level and create a **function** where you register this token on **Your server**. Then accessing this property in that function, you can recall the function and re register as many times as you want on **your** server rather than re-registering on the ***Apple*** server.