# Can a single iOS app installation have two valid apns tokens simultaneously?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27133255/how-to-get-ios-push-notification-token-after-app-launch#comment42767059_27133255) says:

> silent push is the only way that your server can make your app send some data whenever it needs. But this works only when you already have a valid token.

This implies that to periodically get the latest valid apns token once the user stops launching the app: (1) The remote server sends a silent push using token X it got from an earlier app launch, then (2) the silent push causes the app's code to run which gets the token Y from apns library and sends it to the remote server.

If token X != token Y, which of these is true:

- token X and token Y are both valid at the same time
- as soon as the app gets token Y, token X becomes invalid
- the scenario described above (Steps 1 and 2) is not possible

Answer (score 1):

whenever the app lauches then you have to send updated token against that user so there is no way of two FCM token against one user, once you implement slient notification there are a few points that are very important.

1. The **application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)** delegate method will still trigger even though the app is in the foreground.
2. The silent push notification will wake up a terminated app. As a result, the **application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)** delegate method and the initial view controller’s **viewDidLoad()** method will be triggered as well.
3. The background operation triggered by a silent push notification will have roughly **30 seconds** of execution time.

   extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate
   {
   // Once you get new token this delegate call and you need to update user token on server
   func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {

   ```
        let params = ["fcmToken":token,"deviceType":"ios"]
        APIClient.updateFCM(userID:user.ID , bodyParams:params).done { (response) in


        }
    }   

    func setFirebasePushNotification(){

        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        setFirebasePushNotification()
    }
   ```

   }

Please check these links for reference.

https://swiftsenpai.com/testing/send-silent-push-notifications/

https://swiftsenpai.com/testing/send-silent-push-notifications/

Comment: can you please edit your answer to add more precision and detail to "whenever the app lauches then you have to send updated token against that user so there is no way of two FCM token against one user".

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **No**

The application (and libraries like FCM) should update their token using:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) { ... }
```

As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622958-application) says:

> Device tokens can change periodically, so caching the value risks sending an invalid token to your server.

So *as soon as the app gets token Y, token X becomes invalid*

**Note**: [FCM uses method swizzling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client) in two key areas and one of them is [mapping APNs token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#token-swizzle-disabled) So it may be hidden from your implementation but it is updating the token each time its needed and the invalidate the previous one

Comment: Please provide more information instead of copying & pasting what the document says. This is useless.

Comment: What data does OP need that is not in this post or mentioned documents? Please clarify and I would be glad to complete it

Answer (score -1):

No, it can not.

1. From the [Apple official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622958-application)

```
    func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data
    )
```

> Never cache the device token locally on the user's device. **Device tokens can change periodically, so caching the value risks sending an invalid token to your server.** If the device token hasn't changed, registering with APNs and returning the token happens quickly.

You may need to call this function: [registerForRemoteNotifications()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623078-registerforremotenotifications), whenever your app becomes active, again. Submit this deviceToken to Firebase Messaging, your BE, OneSignal,...

```
func registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

When you call the above method, it will request APNs to get a new or current device token. This is the moment that APNs will identify your App & Device status.

2. Why does it change periodically? **Here are the mechanics, methods, or reasons why Apple may use, do in changing DeviceToken, this is used for explaining what will or may happen behind the scenes, they are both theories and facts**.

- This is how Apple does to improve user experience. Changing the Token periodically is like your app call /refresh-token to BE to get a new token. Because the old token has already expired or is invalid. This increases security, protects user's privacy, etc. Imagine that you can still spam push notifications to user's devices when the app is deleted/uninstalled, this is a horrible UX.
- Push Notification is processed/transferred over the Internet connection. Apple Push Notification service will have to check your Device & App periodically to ensure that your Phone is alive and installed, to successfully send a push notification to the target App on the target Device.

Comment: Almost all of the "Why" section information is not true and just false assumptions. For example, the token can not be related to the IP or wifi.
Token changes are not related to checking the device's living and they are not because of handling UX issues

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Give me your evidence, proof, or anything that proves that I'm wrong, man. At least, I gave him informative things that can be used in identify what happens.

Comment: > Notification may not work if you connect to another router because to token may change on this event (Absolutely wrong!). Imagine the device should refresh your entire application library tokens on the IP or wifi change. Do you need anything to figure out that its **Absolutely WRONG**? 

Remember that the token is for you and your server to communicate! not for Apple! Apple has always access to all of its devices using a stable low resource consuming connection and using it for the push service

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini
Did you understand this line: "You can imagine that..."? I just gave him some ideas, mechanics, and reasons that can cause "token changes periodically". I was telling about "Mechanics of changing periodically", not telling "What exactly makes the change". If I were a member of Apple Core Developer team, I didn't need to write these long texts.

So, if you think I was wrong, please give us some reasons why the device_token change, when users still keep using the app, no reinstall,... From what you just said, Apple always has access to iOS device, so why token needs to change?

Comment: Yes my friend and I said that those are false assumptions. Yes, I can give you a clue about that: 1. Install/Reinstall 2. Restore backup from another device, 3. Changes in the structure of the token
These are 3 known reasons

Comment: I think you misunderstand the token concept. The token is a way for developers to access their apps running on users' devices. Not for Apple. Apple gives the access to the developer through the token